# Odoo-15. Error 500 aufter updating Python packages and rebooting the server

Tags: odoo-15

we are running an Odoo 15.0 Community Edition on an Ubuntu 18.04.6 server.
We did the installation using the install script from Yenthe666.
Everything worked fine, so that we started to customize our installation by modifying reports through creating new modules inherited Qweb reports.
This was ok until we had to update a few packages (mainly Python 3.10) and reboot our server.
We ended up with a Odoo instance that only shows an 500 Internal Server Error page.

We checked our Python version:

```
python3 --version
```

=> 3.8.13 (the version we needed to upgrade to during installation)

When we stop and start the Odoo-server with:

```
sudo -u odoo /odoo/odoo-server/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo-server.conf
```

we get the following messages in our logfile:

```
2022-08-10 17:52:48,138 23825 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 15.0 
2022-08-10 17:52:48,138 23825 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo-server.conf 
2022-08-10 17:52:48,138 23825 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/odoo/odoo-server/addons', '/odoo/custom/addons'] 
2022-08-10 17:52:48,139 23825 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@odoo.ourserver.com:5432 
2022-08-10 17:52:48,284 23825 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
2022-08-10 17:52:48,545 23825 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on odoo.ourserver.com:8069
```

so everything seems to be OK

When we stop the service and restart it as a service

```
systemctl start odoo-server
```

we get the same messages in the logfile.

When we check the status of the service with:

```
systemctl status odoo-server
```

we get the following:

```
● odoo-server.service - LSB: Enterprise Business Applications
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/odoo-server; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-10 20:17:34 CEST; 4min 35s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18422 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/odoo-server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28100 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/odoo-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4630)
   CGroup: /system.slice/odoo-server.service
           └─28112 python3 /odoo/odoo-server/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf

Aug 10 20:17:34 map systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enterprise Business Applications...
Aug 10 20:17:34 map odoo-server[28100]: Starting odoo-server: odoo-server.
Aug 10 20:17:34 map systemd[1]: Started LSB: Enterprise Business Applications.
```

When we try to access the site it only shows an 500 Internal Server Error and the log file shows the following messages and ends with an Permission Error:

```
2022-08-10 18:24:30,128 28112 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
2022-08-10 18:24:30,132 28112 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2022 18:24:30] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.002
2022-08-10 18:24:30,137 28112 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/server.py", line 482, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 112, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 87, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1336, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1302, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1487, in dispatch
    explicit_session = self.setup_session(httprequest)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1367, in setup_session
    session_gc(self.session_store)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 26, in __get__
    value = self.fget(obj)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1313, in session_store
    path = odoo.tools.config.session_dir
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/config.py", line 710, in session_dir
    os.makedirs(d, 0o700)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/odoo/.local' - - -
```

We do not know where to look, to see, what really causes the 500 Internal Server Error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you haven't set up a proper virtual environment and as well as the user and the environment values in the startup script to the same environment you ran initially. The environmental values change between running the script under a specific user (or even root) to running it in a start up script as root.
That being said, you need to give permission to `/odoo/.local` for Odoo to create the necessary folders. Check which users have access to that folder and its contents.
Always read the last sentence of the error output more carefully: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/odoo/.local'`

Comment: Thx. After granting permissions to Odoo user it finally works.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer than =)